# Grouping CSS classes vs Individual Classes when have same attributes Performance - SASS/SCSS implementation

Tags: html, css, performance, sass

Previously without SASS if classes share the same CSS attributes it's easier to group them as below

```
.header, .content, .footer {
   height:100%;

}
```

but with SASS/SCSS etc managing styles are so much easier. 
So the question is given the CSS performance consideration givent the mixin below

```
@mixin sameHeight{  
   height:100%;
}
```

should the implementation be

```
.content {
  @include sameHeight; 
}

.footer {
  @include sameHeight; 
}

.header {
  @include sameHeight; 
}

/* CSS OUTPUT */

  .header {
       height:100%;

 }

  .content{
       height:100%;
 }

  .footer{
       height:100%;
 }
```

Or should it be

```
.header, .content, .footer {
   @include sameHeight; 

}

/* CSS OUTPUT */
.header, .content, .footer {
       height:100%;   
}
```

Comment: Focus on maintainability, the performance differences are minimal. Make sure you minimize and gzip in production.

Comment: I don't think there is much maintainability issues but performance can be affected if you have something like this http://s1.wp.com/wp-content/themes/pub/twentytwelve/style.css?m=1367965626g

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the performance differences, the different structures did not really change the performance on my server, you might have to test it yourself.

Writing the same thing over and over again in CSS will make the file bigger ... and bigger filer = a bit longer time to load & render. And generally we should try to avoid redundancies.

But the structure, I think, mostly depends on how the whole file is organized ... and what else you want to do with the same classes.

You might also look into `@extend`, where you can achieve the same by doing something like:

```
@mixin sameHeight{  
   height:100%;
}
.header {
   @include sameHeight; 
}
.content {
   @extend .header;
}
.footer {
   @extend .content;
}
```

but as I said ... **it all depends on the operations you want to do on things ... and how you want the rules to inherit properties**.

At the end the preprocessors are mostly there to make it easier for you to style things.

**EDIT:** For CSS performance testing you might try [Andy's stress test](http://edinborough.org/CSS-Stress-Testing-and-Performance-Profiling).

Comment: ok let me give a bit more practical example http://s1.wp.com/wp-content/themes/pub/twentytwelve/style.css?m=1367965626g where you may have `article.format-quote footer.entry-meta,
article.format-link footer.entry-meta,
article.format-status footer.entry-meta {
 font-size: 11px;
 font-size: 0.785714286rem;
 line-height: 2.181818182;
}
` now there are many instances like that in this particular style sheet

Comment: I am not completely sure what you want me to do with this file ... I updated the answer ... i tried it out on my server ... and it does not change much on performance ... but as I wrote ... if the file CSS gets unnecessarily really long, it might also take a bit longer to load.

Comment: here some slides on github webpage performance ... has some general useful hints on css performance: https://speakerdeck.com/jonrohan/githubs-css-performance

Comment: For css performance testing ... you can try something like this http://edinborough.org/CSS-Stress-Testing-and-Performance-Profiling, before I pasted the wrong link ... sorry.

Comment: Maybe this can be of some help too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558460/how-to-test-css-selector-performance/3571136#3571136